# Complete all entries of a column by a specific value by id

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with the following "ladder" structure

```
     a1   c1     p1   q1   s1   id
596 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
597 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
598 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
599 <NA> <NA> 719800 <NA> <NA>  2
600 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
601 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
602 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
603   44 <NA>   <NA>    1    1  2
604 <NA> <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>  2
```

Each variable only appear once for each id and different variables can come in different rows.

I want to have a single row for each id. My idea was to repeat values in each column by id and then drop the duplicates, so I would have the following.

```
a1   c1     p1   q1   s1   id
44   NA  719800   1    1    2
```

However, I could not think of a general approach for that. I have to run this task over many similar data sets, so I have to write it as generically as possible.

Comment: `colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Forgot to mention I have some string columns as well, so colSums won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(funs(na.omit(.)[1]))

# A tibble: 1 × 6
#     id     a1    c1     p1     q1     s1
#  <int> <fctr> <lgl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
#1     2     44    NA 719800      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base R` option with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~id, df1, na.omit, na.action = NULL)
```

and to get the `NA` for columns that have all NA is to pass an anonymous function

```
aggregate(.~id, df1, function(x) na.omit(x)[1], na.action = NULL)
#  id a1   c1     p1 q1 s1
#1  2 44 <NA> 719800  1  1
```

According to the `?aggregate` documentation `na.action` argument by default ignore missing values

> The default is to ignore missing values in the given variables.

Therefore, we specify it with `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
tes <- read.delim(text = 'a1 c1 p1 q1 s1 id
NA NA NA NA NA 2
NA NA NA NA NA 2
NA NA NA NA NA 2
NA NA 719800 NA NA 2
NA NA NA NA NA 2
NA NA NA NA NA 2
NA NA NA NA NA 2
44 NA NA 1 1 2
NA NA NA NA NA 2
NA 3 NA NA NA 3
2 NA NA NA NA 3', sep = ' ')


vec <- unique(tes$id)
ans <- NULL
for(v in 1:length(vec)){
  subs.v <- subset(tes, tes$id == vec[v])
  vals.v <- apply(subs.v, 2, function(x) {
    un.vals <- unique(na.omit(x))
    ifelse(length(un.vals) == 0, NA, un.vals)
  }
  )
  ans <- rbind(ans, vals.v)
}

ans
       a1 c1     p1 q1 s1 id
vals.v 44 NA 719800  1  1  2
vals.v  2  3     NA NA NA  3
```